# Modular Power supply, using other types of modular cables?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, cable

I have a corsair cx600 modular Power supply. I ordered from a company corsair cx500 modular cable by mistake.( a 6pin male to 6pin male cable) This was so I could connect my new GPU, a small form factor geforce Gtx 960.

Will this cable work with my cx600 powersupply? I figure as long as the heads are the same and "fit" it would not matter.

Comment: I guess as long as the cable fits, you are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the pin outs are the same(no crossovers or combinations) and the connectors fit, there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: How can i tell this would happen? If the pin outs are the same?

Comment: Just follow the wires from the power supply to the plug. You should be able to easily see if any cables skip pins or combine with another wire in a pin. 6-pin connectors are common, so I wouldn't think you would have any issues just plugging it in

Comment: There is only a jack for inputting the 6pin though for the Power supply itself, the wire is suppose to be inputed into the powersupply directly, and into the GPU directly, so do you mean the wires inside the PSU itself?